# ¿Cómo consultar una columna de la tabla a donde apunta la FK?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla libro que tiene una FK categoría. He hecho una consulta para extraer tanto el id como el nombre de la tabla referenciada. El caso es que necesito además de ello, extraer la columna nombre (nombre_categoria). Pero no consigo averiguar la forma de añadir nada más allá del id y el nombre de la tabla de la siguiente forma:

```
select 
    referenced_table_name, referenced_column_name
from
    information_schema.key_column_usage
where
    referenced_table_name is not null
    and TABLE_NAME = 'tbl_libros'
    and table_schema = 'bd_libreria'
```

Su estructura es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me explico mejor:

Lo que quiero hacer, es que la consulta "detecte" la tabla a la que apunta la FK, obtenga el nombre de la columna id y además, seleccione la columna nombre_categoría. Todo ello de forma automática. Es decir, si yo ahora cambiase a otra tabla distinta con nombres diferentes, pero con el mismo escenario, debería de seguir funcionando solo con indicarle la tabla que contiene la FK. El resto se haría "solo".

Comment: añade por favor la estructura de las tablas

Comment: deseas extraer los datos de la tabla libro, además de eso quieres obtener por cada registro el nombre de la categoría con la cual fue guardado cada registro?

Comment: Que deseas obtener realmente ?

Comment: @anonimo, @josanangel. Pues veréis, todo viene de que necesito hacer una consulta que obtenga automáticamente el id al que apunta la FK de la tabla libro, que en este caso apunta al id_categoria y obtener también el nombre de la tabla categoría. Hecho esto, quiero que la consulta acceda también a la columna nombre_categoria, para crear un select en donde en lugar del id se vea el nombre de la categoría.
O lo que es lo mismo quiero obtener esta consulta:  ```SELECT id_categoria, nombre_categoria FROM `tbl_categoria` ``` pero sin tener que indicarlo manualmente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te propongo hacer un `JOIN` de lo que ya tienes con la tabla `COLUMNS`:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME 'REFERENCED_TABLE_OTHER_COLUMNS',
      TABLE_SCHEMA CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA,
      TABLE_NAME REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME
      FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
  ) c1 JOIN (
    SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,
      REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME,
      CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
      FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
      WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA='bd_libreria'
      AND TABLE_NAME='tbl_libros'  
  ) c2 USING(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA,REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME);
```

Así obtendrás el resto de los campos de la tabla referenciada en `REFERENCED_TABLE_OTHER_COLUMNS`

Comment: GRANDE! Llevaba dias intentando hacerlo y no me salia. Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Estaba intentando hacer un filtrado con un ```and like``` usando la ```REFERENCED_TABLE_OTHER_COLUMNS```, pero no me reconoce la columna haga lo que haga.

Comment: Pues, ya sabes, lanza una nueva pregunta, y a ver si damos con ello... :), ¿podemos apoyarnos en PHP?